# Como efetuar parse no retorno da classe SoapClient método __getFunctions()

Tags: php

Consultei um **Web Service** utilizando a classe `SoapClient` do `PHP` e o método `__getFunctions()` para listar os serviços disponibilizados por este **Web Service**.

Obtive o retorno abaixo:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ConsultarResponse Consultar(ConsultarRequest $ConsultarRequest)
    [1] => ConsultarTipoResponse, ObjResponse ConsultarTipo(ConsultarTipoRequest $ConsultarTipoRequest)
)
```

Como faço um parse para pegar a palavra que vem antes do parentes? A ideia seria ignorar tudo e pegar somente a ocorrência que vem a esquerda do parentes.

O retorno teria que ser:

- Constular
- ConsultarTipo

Comment: A palavra `Consultar` ?

Comment: no primeiro seria Consultar e na segunda linha ConsultarTipo. Sempre pegar a primeira sentença que vem antes de parentes. Por exemplo: ConsultarResponse Consultar_tipo(ConsultarRequest $ConsultarRequest) seria que pegar somente Consultar_tipo.

Answer (score 1):

Com uma ER bem estruturada, você realiza isso em poucas linhas.

Em primeiro lugar, é importante entender que até a [nomenclatura de métodos segue uma expressão regular](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php):

```
'^[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*$'
```

A partir disso, pode-se ampliar a expressão regular para buscar sempre que houver um nome de método, compatível com a expressão regular acima, entre um espaço em branco e a abertura de um parênteses:

```
'\s[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*\(/'
```

Como você deseja extrair apenas o nome do método, é importante incluir em um grupo (que eu nomarei de method):

```
'\s(?P<method>[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)\(/'
```

E o código para uso:

```
$stringList = [
    'ConsultarResponse Consultar(ConsultarRequest $ConsultarRequest)',
    'ConsultarTipoResponse, ObjResponse ConsultarTipo(ConsultarTipoRequest $ConsultarTipoRequest)'
];

$matches = [];

foreach($stringList as $string) {   
    preg_match(
        '/\s(?P<method>[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)\(/',
        $string,
        $matches
    );

    printf("Método: %s <br />" , $matches['method']);
}
```

Saída:

```
Método: Consultar 
Método: ConsultarTipo
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar a função `strpos()` para descobrir a posição do primeiro espaço e do abre prentese, com isso é possível determinar qual o trecho que deve ser 'recortado' com a função `substr()` ou seja começa em depois da ocorrência do espaço (`$espaço+1`) e copia N caracteres isso feito com `$parentese - $espaco -1`.

```
$arr = array('ConsultarResponse Consultar(ConsultarRequest $ConsultarRequest)',
             'ConsultarTipoResponse ConsultarTipo(ConsultarTipoRequest $ConsultarTipoRequest)'
            );

foreach($arr as $item){
    $espaco = strpos($item, ' ');
    $parentese = strpos($item, '(');
    echo substr($item, $espaco+1, $parentese - $espaco -1) .'<br>';
}
```

Pode utilizar uma regex com um grupo (`$m[1]`) para captura extamente o que está entre o espaço (`\s+`) e o parentese.

```
foreach($arr as $item){
    preg_match('/\s+(\w+)\(/', $item, $m);
    echo $m[1] .'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Pode ser que existam mais de um espaço antes do método. Por exemplo: ConsultarResponse, ObjResponse Consultar(ConsultarRequest $ConsultarRequest). Então será necessário pegar somente a ocorrência anterior ao parênteses. Acho que seria algo como, possui um espaço é é precedida por parênteses?

Comment: @Fábio editei a resposta.

Comment: a Regex ajudou bastante, porém, ainda preciso que seja retornado a ocorrência a esquerda do parênteses, delimitador final parênteses e delimitador inicial último espaço antes do parênteses.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo modelo apresentado, sua consulta seria algo assim:

```
$parametro = 'Sua consulta';

$client = new SoapClient('http://path/seuwebservice.wsdl');
$client->ConsultarResponse->Consultar($parametro);
$client->ConsultarTipoResponse->ConsultarTipo($parametro);
```

Para fazer um parse disso, seria basicamente assim:

```
$return  = $client->__getFunctions();

list($use, $notUse) = explode('(', $return[0]);
list($ConsultarResponse, $Consultar) = explode(' ',$use);
//primeiro
echo $Consultar;

list($useTwo, $notUseTwo) = explode('(',$return[1]);
list($ConsultarTipoResponse, $ConsultarTipo) = explode(', ObjResponse ', $useTwo);
//segundo
echo $ConsultarTipo;
```

Veja o exemplo no [**IDEONE**](http://ideone.com/LmjSOq)